# How to use a submodule in my gitlab runner?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

On https://gitlab.com

1. I created a private group called test-kirby-group.
2. I created a private project in that group called test-project-1
3. I created another private project in that group called test-sub-project
4. I instantiated both new projects with a default readme.
5. In test-kirby-group/test-project-1 , i added a .gitmodules file

```
[submodule "vendor/submodules/test-sub-project"]
    path = submodules/test-sub-project
    url = ../../test-group-kirby/test-sub-project.git
```

6. In test-kirby-group/test-project-1 , i added a .gitlab-ci.yml file

```
variables:
    GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive

before_script:
    - apk update && apk add git
    - git submodule sync --recursive
    - git submodule update --init --recursive

test:
    script:
        - pwd
        - ls -al
        - ls -al ../
        - ls -al ../../
```

... I then checked the job output ...

```
Running with gitlab-runner 12.3.0 (a8a019e0)
  on docker-auto-scale ed2dce3a
Using Docker executor with image ruby:2.5 ...
Pulling docker image ruby:2.5 ...
Using docker image sha256:e216e233b2581d7f45d2bc2c4dce4f1f293267b29c45bfd929d038a9a67b4058 for ruby:2.5 ...
Running on runner-ed2dce3a-project-15133453-concurrent-0 via runner-ed2dce3a-srm-1572642947-b5456b44...
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/test-group-kirby/test-project-1/.git/
Created fresh repository.
From https://gitlab.com/test-group-kirby/test-project-1
 * [new ref]         refs/pipelines/93160262 -> refs/pipelines/93160262
 * [new branch]      master                  -> origin/master
Checking out b624748a as master...

Updating/initializing submodules recursively...
$ apk update && apk add git
/bin/bash: line 89: apk: command not found
$ git submodule sync --recursive
$ git submodule update --init --recursive
$ pwd
/builds/test-group-kirby/test-project-1
$ ls -al
total 48
drwxrwxrwx. 3 root root 4096 Nov  1 21:17 .
drwxrwxrwx. 4 root root 4096 Nov  1 21:17 ..
drwxrwxrwx. 6 root root 4096 Nov  1 21:17 .git
-rw-rw-rw-. 1 root root  274 Nov  1 21:17 .gitlab-ci.yml
-rw-rw-rw-. 1 root root  141 Nov  1 21:17 .gitmodules
-rw-rw-rw-. 1 root root   18 Nov  1 21:17 README.md
$ ls -al ../
total 32
drwxrwxrwx. 4 root root 4096 Nov  1 21:17 .
drwxrwxrwx. 3 root root 4096 Nov  1 21:17 ..
drwxrwxrwx. 3 root root 4096 Nov  1 21:17 test-project-1
drwxrwxrwx. 3 root root 4096 Nov  1 21:17 test-project-1.tmp
$ ls -al ../../
total 24
drwxrwxrwx. 3 root root 4096 Nov  1 21:17 .
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 4096 Nov  1 21:17 ..
drwxrwxrwx. 4 root root 4096 Nov  1 21:17 test-group-kirby
Job succeeded
```

Question: 
1. Should I expect to see a directory called vendor?
2. If so, why didn't it clone?

Comment: How did you add your submodule? Did you do `git submodule add <>` or did you just add a `.gitmodules` to your repo?

Comment: I did not use `git submodule add <>`.  Should I have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you may have not added the `git submodule` correctly.

In `test-kirby-group/test-project-1` do the following:

- Remove the current `.gitmodules` which was created manually
- Run `git submodule add <git@gitlab ...> <path/to/submodule>`
- You might need to now edit the generated `.gitmodules` from the above command to use a relative URL (i.e. what you already have `url = ../../test-group-kirby/test-sub-project.git`), for it to work with [GitLab CI](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/git_submodules.html#using-git-submodules-in-your-ci-jobs)
- You shouldn't need your current `before_script`, as long as you are using `gitlab-runner` v1.10+, you only need the following in your CI script:

```
variables:
    GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive
```

See [Using Git submodules with GitLab CI](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/git_submodules.html) for more information.