# gitlab CI submodules is not shown even though the log says initializing submudules

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Following the solution on [How to use a submodule in my gitlab runner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58666155/how-to-use-a-submodule-in-my-gitlab-runner/76409043#76409043)

.gitlab-ci.yml:

```
variables:
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive
...
job1:
  script:
    - ls -a
```

.gitmodules

```
[submodule "test"]
    path = test
    url = .....
```

I see this in the gitlab job console:
Updating/initializing submodules recursively with git depth set to 20...
but I don't see the "test" folder listed by the ls -a command

Comment: So you've placed an answer to another question two days ago that was not accepted as reference for your new question here that this should work? Couldn't it be that what you only recently learned working did not work longer than two days? No offence, this is a pretty valid case asking a question IMHO, I only have a problem to understand specifically what you have tried and what your _current_ understanding is. Especially I miss reference to `GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY`. It is good practice you provide at least a hyperlink so it is clear what you refer to (I have a guess, but that is speculative).